# Adding CSRF anti-spoofing to Sencha forms

Tags: php, extjs, joomla, sencha-touch-2, csrf

I made Sencha frontend app and its backend was done with PHP/Joomla. Data sent by Sencha JS app is validated and saved using PHP with Joomla framework.

How can i create CSRF token in Sencha JS app and validate it back on PHP/Joomla code

Answer (score 0):

Joomla forms are protected with a token which is checked on every new post. The token is simply a hidden field which you insert into a form with

```
echo JHtml::_('form.token');
```

This is checked in the controller with something like

```
JSession::checkToken('post') or jexit(JText::_('JInvalid_Token'));
```

This works fine for standard get/post interaction. But if you're going Ajax, you will need a way to retrieve a new token after each request is made:

You controller would then have to return

```
JSession::getFormToken()
```

to the frontend, which should include it in its next call.

**Beware:** make sure the ajax responses are not cached: while the hidden token input inserted with the first code snippet is handled properly by the page cache, you must take care of updating any other occurrence.